# Why is binutils-gdb failing to build from MSYS2?

Tags: windows, gdb, autotools, msys2, binutils

I'm trying to build binutils-gdb on a Windows 10 PC from within the msys2 environment.

```
git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

Most of the code is compiling OK, but libiberty is failing to build with errors in pex-win32.c:

```
./pex-win32.c:121:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_open’; did you mean ‘open’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
./pex-win32.c:121:23: error: ‘_O_RDONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_RDONLY’?
```

(note: above is a sample of the first couple of compilation errors).

I am suspecting that I need to pass an option to ./configure to correct this but not sure what it is. I am currently running ./configure with no options.

By default, the build, host, and target system type are all set to x86_64-w64-mingw32.

```
configure:2678: checking build system type
configure:2692: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

If I run the pre-processor on pex-win32.c, I can see that it is including this declaration for open:

```
# 201 "/usr/include/sys/_default_fcntl.h" 2 3 4

extern int open (const char *, int, ...);
```

But pex-win32.c doesn't use open, it uses _open (and there are similar issues with other symbols with the underscore in the pex-win32.c file but not the headers).

```
return _open (name, _O_RDONLY | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT));
```

Further down in the _default_fcntl.h header I see the correct declaration wrapped in an #ifdef _COMPILING_NEWLIB:

```
/* Provide _<systemcall> prototypes for functions provided by some versions
of newlib.  */
#ifdef _COMPILING_NEWLIB
extern int _open (const char *, int, ...);
```

However if I pass CFLAGS+="-D_COMPILING_NEWLIB" to make, then it creates other build errors, and I don't think that is the answer.

Any ideas on how to get binutils-gdb to build from the msys2 environment?

Thanks!

**Update**

I have tried to reproduce building the msys2 gdb package.

This fails with:

```
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

full output:

```
MSYS /
$cd /d/git

MSYS /d/git
$echo $MSYSTEM
MSYS

MSYS /d/git
$git clone https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages.git
Cloning into 'MSYS2-packages'...
remote: Counting objects: 19033, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
remote: Total 19033 (delta 31), reused 81 (delta 25), pack-reused 18911
Receiving objects: 100% (19033/19033), 16.14 MiB | 9.82 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9917/9917), done.

MSYS /d/git
$cd MSYS2-packages/gdb

MSYS /d/git/MSYS2-packages/gdb
$makepkg -sCLf --skippgpcheck
==> Making package: gdb 7.12.1-1 (Mon, Jul 30, 2018  4:12:59 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Downloading gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18.3M  100 18.3M    0     0  8187k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 8187k
  -> Downloading gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz.sig...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    72  100    72    0     0    295      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   295
  -> Found gdbinit
  -> Found 0001-Teach-gdb-how-to-unwind-cygwin-_sigbe-and-sigdelayed.patch
  -> Found 0002-7.8-windows-nat-cygwin.patch
  -> Found 0003-Better-handling-for-realpath-failures-in-windows_mak.patch
  -> Found 0004-7.8-symtab-cygwin.patch
  -> Found 0005-Remove-a-spurious-target_terminal_ours-from-windows_.patch
  -> Found 0006-PR-build-21187-Static-linking-of-libstdc-and-libgcc-.patch
  -> Found 0010-Support-settings-thread-name-MS-Windows.patch
  -> Found gdb-7.11.1-msysize.patch
==> WARNING: Skipping verification of source file PGP signatures.
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz ... Passed
    gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz.sig ... Skipped
    gdbinit ... Passed
    0001-Teach-gdb-how-to-unwind-cygwin-_sigbe-and-sigdelayed.patch ... Passed
    0002-7.8-windows-nat-cygwin.patch ... Passed
    0003-Better-handling-for-realpath-failures-in-windows_mak.patch ... Passed
    0004-7.8-symtab-cygwin.patch ... Passed
    0005-Remove-a-spurious-target_terminal_ours-from-windows_.patch ... Passed
    0006-PR-build-21187-Static-linking-of-libstdc-and-libgcc-.patch ... Passed
    0010-Support-settings-thread-name-MS-Windows.patch ... Passed
    gdb-7.11.1-msysize.patch ... Passed
==> Removing existing $srcdir/ directory...
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting gdb-7.12.1.tar.xz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
patching file gdb/amd64-windows-tdep.c
patching file gdb/i386-cygwin-tdep.c
patching file gdb/windows-tdep.c
patching file gdb/windows-tdep.h
patching file gdb/windows-nat.c
patching file gdb/windows-nat.c
patching file gdb/symtab.c
patching file gdb/windows-nat.c
patching file gdb/ChangeLog
patching file gdb/NEWS
Hunk #1 succeeded at 142 with fuzz 2 (offset 141 lines).
patching file gdb/windows-nat.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 173 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 454 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1063 (offset 20 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1091 (offset 19 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1173 (offset 19 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 1224 (offset 19 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 1580 (offset 19 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 2591 (offset 17 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 2623 (offset 17 lines).
patching file bfd/acinclude.m4
Hunk #1 succeeded at 21 (offset -2 lines).
patching file bfd/config.bfd
Hunk #1 succeeded at 729 with fuzz 2 (offset 50 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 782 with fuzz 2 (offset 51 lines).
patching file bfd/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 5996 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 6338 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 6918 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 8502 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 8584 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 9046 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 9161 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 9592 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 10493 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 10524 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 11166 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 13767 (offset 97 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 13943 (offset -1015 lines).
Hunk #14 succeeded at 14098 (offset -1015 lines).
patching file bfd/configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 267 (offset -316 lines).
patching file config/dfp.m4
patching file config/elf.m4
Hunk #1 succeeded at 15 with fuzz 2 (offset 2 lines).
patching file config/lthostflags.m4
patching file config/mmap.m4
patching file config/picflag.m4
Hunk #1 succeeded at 25 (offset 6 lines).
patching file config/tcl.m4
patching file config.guess
Hunk #1 succeeded at 888 (offset 22 lines).
patching file config.rpath
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 3036 (offset 17 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 3556 (offset 116 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 3569 (offset 118 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 3843 (offset 136 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 3987 (offset 145 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 6138 with fuzz 2 (offset -119 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 6156 (offset -118 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 6167 (offset -118 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 6177 (offset -118 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 7048 (offset -36 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 7556 (offset -29 lines).
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 409 (offset 33 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 892 (offset 127 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 905 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1179 (offset 144 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1323 (offset 153 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 1817 (offset 112 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 1828 (offset 112 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 1838 (offset 112 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 2652 (offset 190 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 3155 (offset 198 lines).
patching file gdb/config/i386/msys.mh
patching file gdb/config/i386/msys64.mh
patching file gdb/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 8002 (offset 901 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 14418 (offset 1285 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 15095 (offset 1062 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 15138 (offset 1062 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 15267 (offset 1062 lines).
patching file gdb/configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 610 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1960 (offset -132 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 2032 (offset -139 lines).
patching file gdb/configure.host
Hunk #1 succeeded at 116 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 184 (offset -4 lines).
patching file gdb/configure.tgt
Hunk #1 succeeded at 239 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 677 with fuzz 2 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 722 (offset 2 lines).
patching file gdb/gdbserver/configure.srv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 111 (offset 13 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 377 (offset 48 lines).
patching file gdb/gnulib/import/Makefile.am
Hunk #1 succeeded at 427 (offset 44 lines).
patching file gdb/gnulib/import/Makefile.in
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1972 (offset 284 lines).
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.base/bigcore.exp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 33 with fuzz 1 (offset -1 lines).
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.base/fileio.exp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 253 (offset 7 lines).
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.base/maint.exp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 138 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 443 (offset -5 lines).
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.base/shreloc.exp
Hunk #2 succeeded at 248 (offset 1 line).
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.base/solib-weak.exp
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.dwarf2/dw2-dos-drive.exp
patching file gdb/testsuite/gdb.server/wrapper.exp
patching file gdb/testsuite/lib/gdb.exp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1802 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 3420 (offset 76 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 3429 (offset 76 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 3454 with fuzz 1 (offset 74 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 3502 (offset 74 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 3621 (offset 74 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 3630 (offset 74 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 3662 (offset 77 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 4070 (offset 79 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 5059 (offset 93 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 5095 (offset 93 lines).
patching file gdb/windows-nat.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 674 with fuzz 2 (offset -8 lines).
patching file libdecnumber/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 4655 (offset 36 lines).
patching file libiberty/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 5109 (offset 212 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 6175 (offset 363 lines).
patching file libiberty/configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 549 (offset 10 lines).
patching file libtool.m4
patching file ltmain.sh
patching file ltoptions.m4
patching file opcodes/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 5718 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 6060 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 6640 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 8225 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 8307 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 8769 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 8884 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 9315 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 10216 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 10247 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 10889 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 12343 (offset 46 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 12513 (offset 46 lines).
patching file opcodes/configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 175 (offset -6 lines).
patching file readline/configure
patching file readline/configure.in
patching file readline/support/config.guess
patching file readline/support/config.rpath
patching file readline/support/config.sub
patching file readline/support/shlib-install
patching file readline/support/shobj-conf
patching file sim/arm/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 6229 (offset 99 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 6571 (offset 99 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 7193 (offset 99 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 9906 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 10450 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 10565 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 10996 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 11897 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 11928 (offset 567 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 12570 (offset 567 lines).
==> Starting build()...
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -p
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking to see if cat works as expected... yes
checking for x86_64-pc-msys-gcc... x86_64-pc-msys-gcc
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...

MSYS /d/git/MSYS2-packages/gdb
$which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

MSYS /d/git/MSYS2-packages/gdb
$gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/7.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /msys_scripts/gcc/src/gcc-7.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)

MSYS /d/git/MSYS2-packages/gdb
$
```

**Update**

remove this from the environment and you can build the gdb package:

```
MSYS_PATH_TYPE=inherit
```

Comment: Windows does not conform to POSIX.  There is a variety of POSIX functions, including `open()`, that it provides under alternative names, instead (*i.e.* `_open()`), or does not provide at all.  This is an issue that requires support in the source code.  There's could be a build-system dimension, too, but that would depend on just how support was set up in the source.  The solution, if any, is project-specific.

Comment: It's possible that nobody has done a msys2-hosted build before and that you need to do the port.  This may not be too hard.  Also, what does `config.guess` return on your system?  Sometimes setting `--host` et al can yield confusing results and if you leave those out, you'll get a more ordinary build

Comment: >  Also, what does config.guess return on your system?
    $ ./config.guess
    x86_64-pc-mingw64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your build environment is incorrect.

MSYS2 has 3 shells (and toolchains)

- MSYS2: posix emulation with msys-2.0.dll (similar to cygwin1.dll).
- MINGW32: 32-bit Windows native
- MINGW64: 64-bit Windows native

the libiberty/configure selects the pex version to use based on this logic:

```
# Figure out which version of pexecute to use.
case "${host}" in
     *-*-mingw* | *-*-winnt*)   pexecute=pex-win32  ;;
     *-*-msdosdjgpp*)       pexecute=pex-djgpp  ;;
     *-*-msdos*)        pexecute=pex-msdos  ;;
     *)             pexecute=pex-unix   ;;
esac
```

If you are using the msys shell (posix emulation) your configure --build should be x86_64-pc-msys, and the logic above should choose pex-unix.c.

Furthermore, if you are wanting to build posix emulated gdb with msys shell, then you should probably be using these patches: https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/gdb.